# JasperReports runtime exception - SAXParseException

Tags: jasper-reports, netbeans-8, wildfly-8

Good day! I am working with Jasper Reports 6.2, JSF 2.2, NetBeans 8.1 and WildFly 8.2, and after one build an exception appeared:

> SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 27; The reference to entity "SOFT" must end with the ';' delimiter.

It is very strange, because I think there is no errors in XML file. The first line that was mentioned, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Since there is no solution currently on the net, I hope that someone who has faced similar problem, will help. Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have some direct URL or HTML characters provided unescaped in the report? You provided only the first line but I suspect something to be wrong within the source code.

For example, if you call somewhere

```
/my/url?param1=2&param2=4
```

this will confuse the SAX parser. So this should become

```
/my/url?param1=2&amp;param2=4
```